# django pagination is not working properly

Tags: python, html, django, paginator

i am trying to do pagination function based-view , it does work but...I m going to give you an example:

If i have a total of 100 results and i want to paginate by 50, it will give 2 pages, but both pages have same 100 results. Cause if i want to paginate by 50 it will give me 2 pages.

I used the the function based view from this **[link](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/03/how-to-paginate-with-django.html)**. i don't want classed view cause if i implement that the rest of the code would not work.

I m going to post a part of my code for this.

**views.py**

```
def search_form_table(request, pk):
    table_name = Crawledtables.objects.get(id=pk)
    t = create_model(table_name.name)
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = AllTablesForm(request.GET)
        if form.is_valid():
           cd = form.cleaned_data
           title = cd['title']
           url = cd['url']
           query = t.objects.filter(title__icontains=title,
                                 url__icontains=url)

           page = request.GET.get('page', 1)

           paginator = Paginator(query, 50)
           try:
              users = paginator.page(page)
           except PageNotAnInteger:
              users = paginator.page(1)
           except EmptyPage:
              users = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

           return render(request, 'search_table.html', {'tbl_name': table_name,
                                                            'users': users,
                                                            'form': form,
                                                            'details': query})
```

Answer (score 1):

I would try to replicate the nice example that you can see on the documentation (it is with a function-based view)!
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/pagination/#using-paginator-in-a-view

As you see page variable is equal to:

```
page = request.GET.get('page')
```

instead of that you are doing

```
page = request.GET.get('page', 1)
```

Pass to request.GET's get() method only one string

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use `get_page()` in pagination.

Just try this:

```
def search_form_table(request, pk):
    table_name = Crawledtables.objects.get(id=pk)
    t = create_model(table_name.name)
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = AllTablesForm(request.GET)
        if form.is_valid():
           cd = form.cleaned_data
           title = cd['title']
           url = cd['url']
           query = t.objects.filter(title__icontains=title,
                                 url__icontains=url)

           paginator = Paginator(query, 50)
           page = request.GET.get('page')
           users = paginator.get_page(page)

           return render(request, 'search_table.html', {'tbl_name': table_name,
                                                            'users': users,
                                                            'form': form,
                                                            'details': query})
```